# FindServers in OPC UA

Tags: c, opc-ua, open62541

I am trying to acquire server capability information of a server, without using multicast Extension(no MDNS).
As FindServers method, works on **applicationDescription**  and **UA_registeredServer** structure, I have modified the structure by adding the two fields needed to accomodate the capability information.

```
typedef struct {
    UA_String serverUri;
    UA_String productUri;
    size_t serverNamesSize;
    UA_LocalizedText *serverNames;
    UA_ApplicationType serverType;
    UA_String gatewayServerUri;
    size_t discoveryUrlsSize;
    UA_String *discoveryUrls;
    UA_String semaphoreFilePath;
    UA_Boolean isOnline;
    //ADDED 
    size_t serverCapabilitiesSize;
    UA_String *serverCapabilities;
} UA_RegisteredServer;

typedef struct {
    UA_String applicationUri;
    UA_String productUri;
    UA_LocalizedText applicationName;
    UA_ApplicationType applicationType;
    UA_String gatewayServerUri;
    UA_String discoveryProfileUri;
    size_t discoveryUrlsSize;
    UA_String *discoveryUrls;
    //ADDED 
    size_t serverCapabilitiesSize;
    UA_String *serverCapabilities;
} UA_ApplicationDescription;
```

Initial configuration of the LDS would be something like this:

```
config->applicationDescription.serverCapabilitiesSize= 2;
    UA_String *caps = (UA_String *) UA_Array_new(2, &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_STRING]);
    caps[0]=UA_String_fromChars("LDS");
    caps[1]=UA_String_fromChars("TEST");
    config->applicationDescription.serverCapabilities = caps;


    UA_StatusCode retval = UA_Server_run(server, &running);
```

Within the register_server_with_discoveryServer, I have added the functionality

```
request.server.serverCapabilitiesSize=server->config.applicationDescription.serverCapabilitiesSize;
    size_t temp_size = server->config.applicationDescription.serverCapabilitiesSize;
    request.server.serverCapabilities = (UA_String*)
            UA_Array_new(temp_size, &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_STRING]);

    if(!request.server.serverCapabilities)
            return UA_STATUSCODE_BADOUTOFMEMORY;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < temp_size; ++i)
        request.server.serverCapabilities[i]=server->config.applicationDescription.serverCapabilities[i];
```

Now when I run the findServers.c code, I expect the value of the serverCapabilities to be shown, when I go into the applicationDescription details.
But I do not get the result.
Inside the FindServers.c code, I print the size of the capabilities. It shows to be 0, But while the server registers it is 2.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < applicationDescriptionArraySize; i++) {
        UA_ApplicationDescription *description = &applicationDescriptionArray[i];
       printf("\n The size: %ld",description->serverCapabilitiesSize);
}
```

And the o/p is:

```
Server[0]: urn:open62541.example.local_discovery_server
    Name: open62541-based OPC UA Application
    Application URI: urn:open62541.example.local_discovery_server
    Product URI: http://open62541.org
    Type: Discovery Server
    Discovery URL:opc.tcp://o755-gksr:4840/
 The size: 0
```

Is it the case that serverCapabililty Identifier is only used with mDNS and cannot be modified to use in cases without mDNS?

[ x] open62541 Version (release number or git tag): v1.2-119-g7bde5f2b

```
Build option: cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DUA_NAMESPACE_ZERO=FULL UA_ENABLE_DISCOVER = ON UA_ENABLE_DISCOVERY_MULTICAST = ON  UA_ENABLE_AMALGAMATION = ON ..
```